# Failing to install streamlit library

Tags: python, machine-learning, streamlit

I've been trying to install streamlit on my VSCode and it keeps popping out the following error:
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6ua2jpht\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cython >= 0.29' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version<'"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"'' setuptools setuptools_scm wheel
cwd: None
Complete output (294 lines):
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.7"' don't match your environment
Collecting cython>=0.29
Using cached Cython-0.29.21-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting numpy==1.16.0
Using cached numpy-1.16.0.zip (5.1 MB)
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-50.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
Collecting setuptools_scm
Using cached setuptools_scm-4.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: cython, numpy, setuptools, setuptools-scm, wheel
Running setup.py install for numpy: started
Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od59egr2\numpy\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od59egr2\numpy\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mptv_yrl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6ua2jpht\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6ua2jpht\overlay\Include\numpy'
cwd: C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od59egr2\numpy
Complete output (273 lines):
Running from numpy source directory.

```
  Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
  with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

    - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                             release)
    - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


  C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od59egr2\numpy\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py:476: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
    return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  blis_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
  get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'  
  customize GnuFCompiler
  Could not locate executable g77
  Could not locate executable f77
  customize IntelVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifl
  customize AbsoftFCompiler
  Could not locate executable f90
  customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable DF
  customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efl
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable gfortran
  Could not locate executable f95
  customize G95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable g95
  customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
  customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efort
  Could not locate executable efc
  customize PGroupFlangCompiler
  Could not locate executable flang
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\',
```

'c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs']
NOT AVAILABLE

```
  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od59egr2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od59egr2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od59egr2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\king_joseph ruvinga\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od59egr2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od59egr2\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
```

### 'define_macros'
warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
creating build
creating build\src.win32-3.8
creating build\src.win32-3.8\numpy
creating build\src.win32-3.8\numpy\distutils
building library "npymath" sources
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od59egr2\numpy\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od59egr2\numpy\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"',
open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mptv_yrl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6ua2jpht\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6ua2jpht\overlay\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\king_joseph ruvinga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\King_Joseph Ruvinga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6ua2jpht\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cython >= 0.29' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version<'"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"'' setuptools setuptools_scm wheel Check the logs for full command output.

Your Assistance would help. Thank You

Comment: Please provide more information. What did you try to use for the install?

Comment: if you get any error after installing  Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0. Please try following -   You have python 3.8 32 bit installed. I think Streamlit doesn't support 32 bit python. I faced this issue recently in PyCharm. Uninstall 32 bit python and install 64 bit from below link and then try installing Streamlit. https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.5/python-3.8.5-amd64.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what the error is and the solution:

`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`